# Detecting whether a browser supports auto-expanding select dropdowns?

Tags: javascript

In IE 6/7/8 a `<select>` element, if given a defined width, does not automatically expand once opened. With browser sniffing (jQuery example was to use `$.browser.msie` and `$.browser.version`) I could detect the current browser to a degree of certainty and, for the relevant browsers add in a custom handler for selects.

In jQuery 1.9 the `$.browser` object has been removed. I am still using an older version in production, and am able to browser sniff and show auto-expanding select menus accordingly; However, this isn't a long term solution if we're going to keep up with the later releases of jQuery.

I've had a look through the properties of select via `for(var i in document.createElement('select')) { ... }` but can't see anything obvious relating to whether or not the menu will automatically expand.

Is there such a thing? Ideally, I'm looking for a vanilla solution that doesn't require browser sniffing. An `if(!property in document.createElement('select')) { ... }` would be fantastic.

[Edit / Addition] I know about jQuery migrate and understand it will probably tide us over. I'm not overly keen to load in more things for one (at the moment) tiny inconvenience.

Comment: IIRC jQuery 2.0+ won't support those browsers anyway. I'd just drop support for that.

Comment: Unfortunately our user-base is made up of ~30% IE7, ~30% IE8. Assuming that 60% is Win XP, they won't be upgrading to IE9 ever and may not know about Chrome / Firefox / Safari / Opera / et al.

Comment: You could at least advise them to upgrade their IE through a message or something

Comment: Some inspiration http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/

Comment: I hadn't thought about conditional statements to apply the javascript; However, I'd rather not use conditionals if I can help it - that way all javascript can be output at the bottom of the page.

Good shout though.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery API of [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/):

> We recommend against using this property; please try to use feature
>   detection instead (see jQuery.support). jQuery.browser may be moved to
>   a plugin in a future release of jQuery.

I investigated and found the [jQuery Migrate Plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) which has the $.browser feature, the code is [available at github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate).

Comment: I know it was deprecated, and that the Migrate plugin exists which patches it; However, I would like to avoid loading a library just to use $.browser.

Ultimately I was looking for a property on the element, or something that lets me know when the feature is there and therefore when to patch it.